# Display Integers in a row format in python

Tags: python

Im trying to figure out a way to get these integers to display in rows while keeping their order.

But when I run the code here's the display I get.

```
Enter numbers 1... 22,34,35,40,55
Enter numbers 2... 12,14,34,47,49
Enter numbers 3... 1,4,10,19,30

Section 1             #
The number seqeuce is 0 between 0 and 9
The number seqeuce is 0 between 10 and 19
The number seqeuce is 1 between 20 and 29
The number seqeuce is 2 between 30 and 39
The number seqeuce is 1 between 40 and 49
The number seqeuce is 1 between 50 and 59
Section 2
The number seqeuce is 0 between 0 and 9
The number seqeuce is 2 between 10 and 19
The number seqeuce is 0 between 20 and 29
The number seqeuce is 1 between 30 and 39
The number seqeuce is 2 between 40 and 49
The number seqeuce is 0 between 50 and 59
Section 3
The number seqeuce is 2 between 0 and 9
The number seqeuce is 2 between 10 and 19
The number seqeuce is 0 between 20 and 29
The number seqeuce is 1 between 30 and 39
The number seqeuce is 0 between 40 and 49
The number seqeuce is 0 between 50 and 59
                      #
```

This is what I would like to see in order 
corresponing to the range integers.

```
Enter numbers 1... 22,34,35,40,55
Enter numbers 2... 12,14,34,47,49
Enter numbers 3... 1,4,10,19,30
Section 1
The number seqeuce is 0 0 1 2 1 1 #
Section 2                         #
The number seqeuce is 0 2 0 1 2 0 # <-- Here is the sequennce from above
Section 3                         #
The number seqeuce is 2 2 0 1 0 0 #
```

Heres what I have so far.

```
import collections  

the_inputs = [] 

for i in range(3): 
    the_inputs.append(raw_input("Enter numbers {}... ".format(i+1))) 

the_lists = [] 

for the_input in the_inputs: 
    the_lists.append([int(x)//10 for x in the_input.strip("[]").split(",")]) 

for i, the_list in enumerate(the_lists): 
    print "Section {}".format(i+1) 
    group_counter = collections.Counter(the_list) 
    bin_range = range (6)  
    for bin_tens in bin_range:
        print "The number seqeuce is {} between {} and {}".format(group_counter[bin_tens], bin_tens*10, bin_tens*10+9)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple rearrangement:

```
print "The number sequence is",
for bin_tens in bin_range:
    print group_counter[bin_tens],
print
```

Comment: this prints out in a colunm format and I think it's breaking down each integer individually.

Comment: @Howie Watch out for the `,` at the end of the `print`. It prevents the `print` from appending a newline.

Comment: this is the same code already in use.  How is this going to make it better or what I'm asking for.

Comment: @Howie: This isn't the code you said you were using, and it produces the numbers in the same format that you asked for.  What does it produce for you when you use it instead of your `for bin_tens in bin_range:` loop?

Comment: Sorry. This works out just right. Still a bit confused but Ill work it out.

Comment: One more question though. When I print with the new code the word setion 1 reads above the number sequence while the word section 2 prints on the same line after the number sequence. How can I correct this.@DSM

Comment: Did you add the extra `print` after the `for` as I did above?  The `,` at the end of a print prevents a newline so the data values appear on one line.  To move to a new line the bare `print` starts a new line.